# What tools do I need to replace a water pump pressure gauge?

Tags: plumbing, well-pump

Do I need to buy tools to be able to change the tank pressure gauge?

Comment: probably just a large enough crescent wrench. If you post a photo that would help.

Comment: A lot of smaller pressure gauges that screw into a pipe thread use an open end wrench turn them. The wrench size is usually 7/16", 1/2", 9/16", or as Kokako wrote a crescent wrench of the appropriate size.

Comment: "*Do I need to buy tools to be able to change the tank pressure gauge?*" We do not know what tools you have.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit of teflon tape for the threads of the new gauge, a bath towel to sop up the water, and a pair of channel locks.

Don't forget to turn off your hot water heater, and somehow relieve the pressure from the gauge first.

Comment: I would give a + for the Teflon tape but the channel locks tear up the brass most gauges are made of If your answer had a crescent or open end wrench instead of channel locks I would up vote.

Comment: Ya, I guess I should add that, as Ed said, this is a brass fitting. I strongly discourage new plumbers using a wrench that could produce too much torque, as fine threaded brass will strip easily. That's why I prefer to use channel locks. A simple quarter to half turn past snug is all that is required, but not knowing the strengrh of the plumber, I try not to suggest that. Me being 6'2", 230lb, my idea of snug may be different from, say, a keyboarder's idea of snug. Channel locks should produce about the right torque.